# Visual SVN 2.0 and IIS

Tags: windows, iis, visualsvn-server

How can I set up Visual SVN Server to run on port 443 and also have IIS set up to handle other website access on port 443?  The URL usually points to /svn/ for the svn server anyway and the other websites point to /fogbugz/ for example.

Or is it possible to have Visual SVN Server just use IIS instead of Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicated question: [Is it possible to bind domain names to VisualSVN server and IIS on the one box without using a port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62912/is-it-possible-to-bind-domain-names-to-visualsvn-server-and-iis-on-the-one-box-wi)

**Option 1: Run VisualSVN Server and IIS on different IP address**
You can run VisualSVN Server and IIS side-by-side on the same port using multiple IP address on network interfaces: http://www.itsyourip.com/networking/how-to-add-multiple-ip-address-in-windows-2000xp2003/

To configure VisualSVN Server bind to only specific interfaces use the following steps:

1. Run VisualSVN Server Manager
2. Right click on root element and choose Properties
3. Switch to Network tab
4. Select "These IP addresses" radio button
5. Click Add Enter IP address of interface to listen
6. Click OK to close Add interface dialog
7. Click OK to close Properties window

To configure IIS listen on specific interface use the following steps:
1. Start elevated command prompt
2. Execute following command: netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=IPADDRESS

**Option 2: Use use reverse proxy for IIS**
Use SvnReverseProxy to redirect traffic from IIS to VisualSVN Server. See following links for details:
http://gstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SvnReverseProxy&ProjectName=gstoolkit

Comment: If I use option 2, will the URL look like https://svnserver.home/svn/repo or will it redirect me to https://svnserver.home:8443/svn/repo?  The redirection won't work.

Comment: URL of your IIS server will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I asked an almost identical question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/62912/is-it-possible-to-bind-domain-names-to-visualsvn-server-and-iis-on-the-one-box-wi). I also have a blog post which contains information on an (admittedly basic) workaround here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/10/creating-your-own-custom-subversion.html