# Prevent IIS7 HTTPS from binding to all SSL IP addresses

Tags: iis-7, ssl, visualsvn-server

I've had this interesting problem with IIS7.

I have a number of HTTPS sites in IIS7.  That hasn't been a problem, until I wanted to go and set up VisualSVN Server using an SSL certificate.  The installer had trouble starting the service.  When I looked in the event log, the error was that "the file is already in use by another process."  I figured that the "file" was really a socket, and checked with netstat - even though IIS was only bound to three specific IP addresses (.160, .156, and .168) with port 443, it was consuming *:443.

I could stop the World Wide Web Publishing Service, start VisualSVN, and then start IIS, but then none of my SSL servers would start.

Any helpful hints about how I could make IIS not try to default-bind to *:443?

Thanks!!

Comment: Bah, if only I'd found the visualsvn-server tag sooner - seems that it's been answered already - http://serverfault.com/questions/75017/visual-svn-2-0-and-iis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/148439/how-can-i-control-which-ip-address-iis7-uses). Use the following command:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```