# How can I control which IP address IIS7 uses?

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

In Win2k3, I used `httpcfg` to tell IIS to listen to specific IP addresses on the server. I want to run Apache with VisualSVN Server on port 80 on another IP address but IIS7 binds to all IP addresses by default.

What utility for IIS7 controls the IIS7 bindings?

Comment: that did the trick, but you have to add ip while http service is working.

Answer (score 24):

I found the answer. There is a utility called `netsh`.

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

By default there are no IP addresses on the list, so IIS7 will bind to all IP addresses. If you add one IP to the list, it will listen to just that IP or any IP added to the list. It is necessary to restart IIS7 for the change to take effect.

**Edit:**

To list the IP addresses, type the following command after the IP address is added:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

The `netsh` utility returns the following information:

```
IP addresses present in the IP listen list: xxx.xxx.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click the "Sites" folder in IIS manager and it lists all the bindings.

*:80 would be the bound to all IP's all unassigned

or

[hostheader] on *:80