# "Could not connect to server" with https(works with http) address to my repository

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2003

I have set up a subversion server with Apache+Subversion on a windows 2003 server machine.
I am able to check out using http, but not using https. It says it cannot connect to the server when using the https address.
Svn version is 1.6.0
Apache version is 2.2.20
I am loading the ssl modules. I have also set up OpenSSL and enabled the ssl.config file in apache.
I am able to talk with my server using my client using netcat and port 443(with TCP) which I was told is used for https.
Not sure what else to do and where to look.
Why am I not able to connect to the server using TortoiseSVN with https? But I can do the same with http?
Thank you,
Ofer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows IIS will effectively take port 443 as a hostage and not allow any other processes to listen to port 443, regardless of bindings.

Even if IIS has no bindings set to the IP address being used for the repository server, IIS will still take the IP address hostage unless IIS is explicitly told which IP addresses to listen to.

There is no GUI in Win Server 2k8 (probably the same for 2k3) to configure the IP addresses for IIS to listen; by default, IIS listens to all IP addresses assigned to the server.

The following will help configure IIS to only listen to the IP addresses you want:

1. open a command prompt
2. enter: `netsh`
3. enter: `http`
4. enter: `show iplisten` --> this will show a table of the IP addresses IIS is listening to. By default, the table will be empty (I guess this means IIS listens to all IP's)
5. For each IP address IIS should listen to, enter: `add iplisten ipaddress=x.x.x.x`
6. enter: `show iplisten` --> you should now see all the IP addresses added to the listening table.
7. Exit and then reset IIS.

Each of these commands can also be run directly, i.e., `netsh http show iplisten`

If you need to delete an IP address from the listening table:

1. open a command prompt
2. enter: `netsh`
3. enter: `http`
4. enter: `delete iplisten ipaddress=x.x.x.x`
5. Exit and then reset IIS.

**Disclaimer**
I had this same problem several months ago and asked the question on ServerFault: [How to run VisualSvn Server on port 443 running IIS on same server](https://serverfault.com/questions/248435/how-to-run-visualsvn-server-on-port-443-running-iis-on-same-server)? The solution provided here is what I came up with and posted on my same question.

Comment: I stopped IIS completely and it still didn't work.

Comment: The problem seemed that I completely forgot to load the mod_ssl.so module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed that I completely forgot to load the mod_ssl.so module.