# Server Farm Configuration on IIS

Tags: iis, rewrite, farm

Is it possible to have a site under IIS that is not part of a server farm if there are other sites in the farm (and have the site reachable)

My setup is that I have TeamCity installed on a Windows server, this is a Tomcat instance listening on port 8081. I have IIS in front of this and I've created a server farm to route request from build.foo.com to localhost:8081

I now want to add a site to IIS that also listens on port 80 called dev.foo.com but when I browse to that site (using http://dev.foo.com) I actually get http://build.foo.com

I have an URL Rewrite rules set like this:

> ARR_TeamCity_LoadBalance, Pattern: *; Using: Wildcards. This routes to
>   the farm TeamCity_Inbound, Pattern: build.foo.com; Using: RegExp. This
>   routes to localhost:8081

As I said I'd like to have dev.foo.com installed on the same IIS server also on port 80 (or at least available over port 80)

I've fiddled with the rewriting settings with no luck, my knowledge of them is limited

I'm not an IIS admin by trade, this is just something I've been tasked to do so any help is greatfully received.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [How can I control which IP address IIS7 uses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/148439/how-can-i-control-which-ip-address-iis7-uses) there is also registry setting for this, but I think the command line is OK.

Comment: Don't think this helps me, the server has a single IP address. It's a hosted server so there's one network card. If we have to go down the path of a second IP address then we'd probably get a second server

Answer (score 1):

This was actually quite simple in the end. I added an HTTP_HOST condition to the ARR rule to only route certain requests to the farm, the rest just drop through to IIS